# How to insert Now Playing into a UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I am trying to grab the current playing sone on iOS 5 and dump the artist and title into a UILabel.  Is this possible?

As far as I was aware on previous versions of the OS I would use;

```
MPMediaPlayer* player = [MPMediaPlayer iPodMusicPlayer];
//get now playing item
MPMediaItem*item = [player nowPlayingItem];
// get the title of song
NSString* titleStr = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
```

But this produces some warnings and does not work.  Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What warnings are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to compile your code, and it looks like you're using the wrong class. You want MPMusicPlayerController, instead of MPMediaPlayer.

```
MPMusicPlayerController* player = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
//get now playing item
MPMediaItem*item = [player nowPlayingItem];
// get the title of song
NSString* titleStr = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
```

This compiles without warnings, I haven't tested it on a device, but this should help.

Comment: Thanks guys, this seems to have solved the issue. thanks again